# Returning unique_ptr or just moving object?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a factory that is creating objects, but I'm unsure what the best way is to return these objects. I have the option to return a `unique_ptr<Trigger>`, or I could just return `Trigger` that is handled by a Move constructor. What is better practice? My best guess is Move because you are guaranteed an object.

```
class TriggerFactory
{
public:
    TriggerFactory();
    ~TriggerFactory();

    Trigger createMyTrigger() const; // Trigger contains a move constructor
};
```

vs

```
class TriggerFactory
{
public:
    TriggerFactory();
    ~TriggerFactory();

    unique_ptr<Trigger> createMyTrigger() const;
};
```

Comment: Normally you want to avoid dynamic allocation if you can.

Comment: Is `Trigger` a base class with virtual functions?

Comment: I would say this depends on how the object is used. Does it need pointer semantics or value semantics? If it can be treated as a value then I would think that would be preferable.

Comment: @ChristianHackl No it is not a base class with virtual functions.

Comment: @Galik that makes sense. I will actually be storing it in a container later so it's probably best if I return a pointer.

Comment: @Taztingo: OK. Then I'd just use the move approach. The golden rule of C++ is to use dynamic allocation only if you have to. But the question is really to broad for a concrete answer.

Answer (score -1):

Frequently the Factory pattern is used for polymorphism: the Factory will return a specific concrete type of some abstract type. In this case it *must* return a pointer to a heap-allocated instance (else the return value will get sliced).

Comment: Not applicable here, see the comments.

Comment: Maybe if the OP edits the question and title this answer won't be applicable, thanks.